# How to add custom parameters in html mail sent via Mailgun using php sdk ?

Tags: php, html, email, mailgun

I am using php sdk to send html mails. I want to add some fields in my html template and then from php set the values of these custom fields. But I don't know how to access custom parameters in html. Lets say "projectName" is my custom parameter then I tried to add proejctName in html using {projectName}, {{projectName}} and {{$projectName}} but none of them are working. I am setting their value by calling the function addCustomParameter(). 
e.g.

```
$messageBldr->addCustomParameter("projectName", "My project Name");
```

But in my email I am getting only html not the value of projectName. If I have more than one custom paramter, do I need to call addCustomParameter () as many time?